# How to connect docker to WSL2 distro

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-toolbox, docker-desktop

I had docker installed as a part of Docker Toolbox which was running docker daemon on my two VirtualBox VMs. I have recently installed WSL2 and Docker Desktop with it. Now I have two docker hosts running, one on Virtual Box VM and another on WSL2. They both work fine, I can manage my WSL docker from inside WSL terminal and Docker Desktop, and I can also work with Virtual Box docker from Docker toolbox.

The problem is when I run docker client from windows cmd it only knows about virtual box machine and if it's off it fails to connect. This also means that VS Code doesn't see my WSL containers.
I tried to create another docker-machine pointed to localhost:2375 but it did not work.

I would like to keep Docker Toolbox as a backup, but I want to change docker client connection to tcp://localhost:2375 instead of VM ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect to wsl by adding a new docker context

`docker context create wsl --docker host=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
 docker contect use wsl`

I also had to update my env variables so they don't override the context